# Extractig data from cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

In this MWE, I generate `dis` (x, y, z displacements for nodes and increments), I then need to extract separately the displacements

```
clear
k=0;
% ignore following, this is just to buils dis
for node=1:20
   for incr=1:100
       k=k+1;
       dis{node,incr}(1)=k; % X coordinate
       dis{node,incr}(2)=2*k; % Y coordinate
       dis{node,incr}(3)=3*k; % Z coordinate
   end
end
```

I would like to build `U`, `V`, `W` arrays from `dis`. However, the
following statement fails:

```
U(:,:)=dis{:,:}(1);
```

Any concise way to make that substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
U = cellfun(@(d) d(1), dis); % change index 1 to 2, 3 for V, W
```

Alternatively,

```
dis_3D = cell2mat(permute(dis, [1 3 2]));
U = permute(dis_3D(:,1,:), [1 3 2]); % change index 1 to 2, 3 for V, W
```

However, consider defining `dis` directly as a 3D array (of size `20`×`100`×`3` in your example), and then everything will be easier. There seems to be no need for a cell array here.

Comment: Elegant, concise coding, but ultimately as cpu intensive as extracting the data from a set of for loops

Comment: @user2260180 I agree, it is not always a good idea to avoid loops. I just like it better without them :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit fiddly. Your `dis` array is a `cell` matrix where each entry is a 1x3 `double` array. I think the first step has to be to get rid of the `cell`-ness and create a regular `double` array. You can do that as follows:

```matlab
arr = [dis{:}];
```

This takes the cells of `dis` in column-major order, and then horizontally concatenates them into one big long vector. You can reshape this into a 3D array by carefully observing the order of the entries:

```matlab
reshaped = reshape(dis, 3, 20, 100);
```

This has the entries in a 3D array, but the dimensions are permuted. So, you can use `permute` to fix it up:

```matlab
fixed = permute(reshaped, [2, 3, 1]);
```

You can then get out `U` by doing

```matlab
U = fixed(:,:,1)
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest also. Cell arrays are misused too often to contain homogeneous data. They are meant to be used for heterogeneous data.